# one column figure along with two column text

Tags: floats, multicolumn

In Latex, I use

```
\onecolumn
\multiplot{3}{fig1,fig2,fig3}
```

to plot figures in one column of my page. However, if I switch to the two column text using

```
\twocolumn
my text is here
```

The text is in a new page! How can I avoid text in the new page just following the one column figure?

The `multiplot` command is defined in the `.cls` file as follows:

```
\newcommand{\multiplot}[5][htbp]{
  \begin{figure*}[#1]
    \centering
    \setcounter{sub@fig}{0}
    \edef\list@i{#3}
    \loop
    \edef\item@i{\expandafter\next@item\list@i,\empty?}
    \edef\list@i{\expandafter\rest@item\list@i,\empty?}
    \ifx\item@i\empty
    \else
    \stepcounter{sub@fig}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[#4]{\fig@file{\item@i}}%
      \label{fig:\@path-\item@i}
      \label{fig:\item@i}}
    \ifthenelse{\value{sub@fig} = #2}{\\ \setcounter{sub@fig}{0}}{}
    \repeat
    \caption{#5}
    \label{fig:\@path-#3}
    \label{fig:#3}
  \end{figure*}
}
```

Comment: please provide a usable test file, you are using `figure*` so the figure will span both columns, so simply remove the `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` commands.

Comment: note your default does no harm but `[htbp]` is the same as `[tp]` which is the same as not using the option as the standard implementation of `figure*` does not support `h` or `b`